# jquery-ui draggable cancel drag for parent

Tags: jquery-ui, leaflet, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a console (div) absolutely positioned a top a `leafletJS` map. I have made it draggable using `jquery-ui draggable` plugin.

The problem is, when I drag the console the underlying map is also dragging. I am unsure as to which event on which element to `stopImmediatePropagation` on and when. Any ideas? I tried cancelling the `click` event on both `start` and `stop` handlers, but to no avail. (its wrapped as an `Angular2+ Directive`).

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({
    selector: '[skinDraggable]'
})
export class DraggableDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('containmentSelector') containmentSelector: string;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        var me = this;
        /** legacy since its available and ng has no decent equivalent */
        $( this.el.nativeElement )
            .draggable({
                containment: this.containmentSelector,
                scroll: false,
                start: (event, ui) => {
                    // event.toElement is the element that was responsible
                    // for triggering this event. The handle, in case of a draggable.
                    $( event.originalEvent.target ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
                }
            });
        this.el.nativeElement.style.cursor = "move";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it, by disabling leaflet dragging on `mousedown` and then reenabling it on `mouseup`. The code shows some `ngrx/store`, but effectively `leafletMap.dragging.enable() and disable()` are being called, but only when the target is the overlay (not the map).

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DraggableDirective} from "../../../widgets/draggable.directive";

import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import * as fromRoot from '../../../app.reducer';
import * as toolbarActions from '../../map-toolbar/map-toolbar.actions';

@Directive({
    selector: '[skinPrintOverlayDraggable]'
})
export class PrintOverlayDraggableDirective extends DraggableDirective implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        el: ElementRef,
        private store: Store<fromRoot.State>
    ) {
        super(el);
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        super.ngOnInit();

        //* preventing the map panning when the user drags the print overlay */
        const mapContainer = document.querySelector('#map-container');
        const map = document.querySelector('.mapboxgl-map');

        mapContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            if (e.target === map) return true;
            this.store.dispatch(new toolbarActions.SwitchDragPanActive(false));
        });
        mapContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
            if (e.target === map) return true;
            this.store.dispatch(new toolbarActions.SwitchDragPanActive(true));
        });
    }
}
```